# How can I make a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If the number that the user enters is less than -100 or more than 200 then I want the program to ask them to " Enter a number between -100 and 200" over and over untill they do so. How can I do this?

```
while r < temp:
    first_year = float(input("What is the first year?"))
    average_temp = float(input("What is the average temputure for the year"))
    if average_temp < -100:
        print  ("Enter a number between -100 and 200")
    if average_temp > 200:
        print ("Enter a number between -100 and 200)
    if averaget_temp <200:
        print ("The average temputure for year" , first_year , "is" , average_temp)
    if average_temp > -100:
            print ("The average temputure for year" , first_year , "is" , average_temp)

    r += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop with `while`.

```
condition = True
while condition:
    # do_something
    condition = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the while loop:

```
while True:
    average_temp = int(input('Number: '))
    if 200 > average_temp > -100:
        break # <----------------- See flow diagram: tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement
    else:
        print('Enter a number between -100 and 200!')
```

Answer (score 0):

One example:

```
number = float(input("Enter a number between -100 and 200: "))
while number<-100 or number>200:
    number = float(input("Enter a number between -100 and 200: "))
print ("Thank you")
```